# iOS: How to Upgrade from cordova 2.5.0 to 3.1.0

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using cordova 2.5.0 now to build my iOS application. Now there is an requirement to upgrade to the latest 3.1.0 version. After searching the internet, I got to know that from version 3.0.0 onwards cordova supports command line interface. But I do not want to use command line interface and want to do it in the current way.

What all changes do I have to do for the upgrade from cordova 2.5.0 to 3.1.0

Please advise me.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. But you should really use the command line interface it will make things easier. I know upgrading seems a painful process and will take some time but you should do it.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS you sould follow steps documented on this page

Comment: You can't use phonegap 3 without command line. The highest version you can use without command line is 2.9.1

Comment: @Benka: Actually I have upgrade from 2.5.0 to directly 3.1.0 and I am not sure what all changes to be done. My main problem is I am not sure how to upgrade to command line mode. Could you please give a short description?

Comment: you have to install Node.js and the Command Line Interface. Then create a new project, add iOS platform and copy all your previous code into the new structure. I would also check the upgrade steps between 2.5.0 and 2.9.1 because there were some minor modifications

Comment: I installed node.js. then I have also run $ sudo npm install -g phone gap command from terminal. But while running create command I am getting error.